# Parsing time string in java 8 - Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm

Tags: datetime, java-8

I am trying to convert time zones with given time in my properties file.

```
 package test1;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimeZoneConversion {

private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String ds = "2019-03-18 13-14-48";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(ds, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
    System.out.println("ldt : "+ldt);

    ZoneId singaporeZoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");
    System.out.println("TimeZone : " + singaporeZoneId);

    //LocalDateTime + ZoneId = ZonedDateTime
    ZonedDateTime asiaZonedDateTime = ldt.atZone(singaporeZoneId);
    System.out.println("Date (Singapore) : " + asiaZonedDateTime);

    ZoneId newYokZoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    System.out.println("TimeZone : " + newYokZoneId);

    ZonedDateTime nyDateTime = asiaZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(newYokZoneId);
    System.out.println("Date (New York) : " + nyDateTime);

    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    System.out.println("\n---DateTimeFormatter---");
    System.out.println("Date (Singapore) : " + format.format(asiaZonedDateTime));
    System.out.println("Date (New York) : " + format.format(nyDateTime));

}
```

}

SO I am getting error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-03-18 13-14-48' could not be parsed: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 13
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
at test1.FirstClass.main(FirstClass.java:20)
```

I do not have AM/PM value in the date time that I getting from properties file. This value is stored in String ds. in the above code I have hardcoded it. How does it work? How to make it work with the time date format which I have given?

Comment: Why can't you change the `DATE_FORMAT ` to accept `HH`instead of `hh`?

Comment: Hi changing it to HH worked. I thought hh and HH would mean same. Does it not? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should change the `DATE_FORMAT` to:

```
 private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss";
```

If you refer the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) docs you see the description as follows:

> H       hour-of-day (0-23)

In your case you are supplying the hour as the `hour-of-day` (`HH`) instead of in `clock-hour-of-am-pm` (`hh a`) format from your properties file. And as `13` ( > 12) is not an acceptable value for `clock-hour-of-am-pm` without the AM/PM you are getting an exception.

If you want it in `clock-hour-of-am-pm` you need to change the format to:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss a";
```

And also add the AM/PM information in the date string:

```
String ds = "2019-03-18 12-14-48 AM";
```

Comment: Was stuck with this issue for a while...my lists were not being sorted as expected and this was the issue. Thanks.